# bootstrap is enqueued but normalize.less doesn't show up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Putting the finishing touches up on this website but having a problem getting the normalize.less page to work. I hooked the bootstrap 3.3.7 cdn into the function.php file. I know bootstrap is loaded because the navbar and contact form depend on the bootstrap grid and they're in the right place. 
The problem is perfectly demonstrated by the buttons (or lack there of). Message me is supposed to be outlined by a grey box shadow. The button also is not supposed to have any text decoration.

the website is www.mustafasprojects.com

if you open the source code you can see there is in fact a stylesheet and that the normalize.less file is loaded but not recognized.

Comment: How are you compiling less to css? What version of bootstrap?

Comment: @bryjohns put the link to the 3.3.7 cdn in my function.php file.

Answer (score 0):

On chrome, inspect page, go to the network tab, Click the css filter then refresh.

I think you have something wrong with your path to normalize.css or your HTTP server rules. If I try to go to http://www.mustafasprojects.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/normalize.css?ver=1.0 - it doesn't bypass wordpress and tries to go a page.

Edit:
amnmustafa15 had style wrapped in a media query so that the styling wouldn't be applied using a standard browser window width.

Comment: I did what you said and checked the status code for the normalize.css and it says 304 - not modified. all the others say 200 - ok. is that what you mean?

Comment: It wasn't working when I looked at it. I also see that normalize.css is working and the bootstrap's normalize.less that gets compiled into bootstrap.css is working. You're looking at source maps, the browser doesn't actually use less files for styling but if you have a source map you can see the less that was used to generate the css file. Were you thinking the bootstrap version wasn't working and tried to add another normailize.css file?

Comment: Also, I don't see any rules as to why you would think "Message me" would be outlined or why "button also is not supposed to have any text decoration"

Comment: in the stylesheet 'style.css?ver=false' is the css for the button indicating the border radius, box shadow and no text decoration. it's on line 2171. I guess I'm getting confused because when I opened the source code on the html file, it says the button's style is derived from bootstrap cdn 3.3.7 normalize.less. specifically on line 302. So if it's not the normalize files do you know what else could cause my button styles to be overwritten?

Comment: You have a media query at line 2121 such that the style never gets applied, if you make the browser width really narrow you will see it applied.